# Magento sudden drop in site speed following no changes

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

My Magento site is running extremely slowly on category pages which has a lot of products. I am presuming this is because of an image issue, however i have optimised and lossy compressed all images making them optimum for our site, furthermore the images on our category page are cached at a correct scale. Is there a reason why our site is taking 9 seconds to retrieve the images? I have also checked with our hosts who ran a tracert, confirming that it is not a server issue. It seems to be down to the instillation but i have no clue where to begin looking as I can't pin down what is causing this issue.

Please see waterfall chart below:

[image: Category Page Waterfall Chart]

Answer (score 0):

This was an extention, the Amasty "Product Labels" . Posting answer for other people with this issue which may also be blamed on an extention